# Finding of value from each column of numpy array is based on comparing of sum from another numpy array

Tags: multidimensional-array, filter, numpy, sum

I have numpy integer array “A” with shape 3x3x3 (for example):

```
[[[***0***,1,0], [1,1,0], [0,1,1]]

[[***1***,1,0], [0,1,1], [0,0,1]]

[[***0***,1,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0]]]
```

And another float array “B” with the same shape:

```
[[[ ***0.19***,0.02,0.65],[ 0.88,0.11,0.07],[ 0.26,0.88,0.17]]

 [[ ***0.13***,0.20,0.48],[ 0.40,0.07,0.67],[ 0.31,0.47,0.01]]

 [[ ***0.40***,0.31,0.92],[ 0.45,0.26,0.53],[ 0.46,0.24,0.47]]]
```

I need the following:

-to count unique values along some axis in first array `A` (for example, `value(0,0,0)`, `value(1,0,0)`, `value(2,0,0))`:

```
0, 1, 0 = > "0" - 2 values  and "1" – 1 value.
```

-calculate appropriate sum from array `B`:

```
0 => 0.19+0.4 = 0.59; 1 => 0.13
```

-find value in array A with maximum sum in array `B`:

```
0.59>0.13 => value 0
```

What is the most efficient way to do such calculation for all values in array `A`?

I need to get result array like `([***0***,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0])`  for example data.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to read each value to sum or compare, the algorithm is expected to have O(n) complexity (where n is the total number of items in the matrix). Here you can find a procedure to compute what you want in O(n) time:

For matrices `A[x][y][z]`, `B[x][y][z]`. Assuming that values in A varies between 0 ad 9.

Since you compute the values for each y-axis we will have a value for `[x,z]` pairs:

```
x: order of tuple in horizontal 
z: order of value in that tuple
```

First, define a weighted sum array that holds sum values for each value in A on each Y-axis: `W[x][z][value]`

Compute weights as follows:

```
for(x=0; x<3; x++) 
{
    for(z=0; z<3; z++) 
    {
        for(y=0; y<3; y++) 
        {
            val = A[x][y][z];
            W[x][z][val] += B[x][y][z];
        }
    }
}
```

Then use this weighted sum array to compute dominant values in A:

```
for(x=0; x<3; x++) 
{
    for(z=0; z<3; z++) 
    {
        maxSum = 0;
        dominantValue = 0;
        for(val=0; val<10; val++)
        {
            if(W[x][z][val] > maxSum)
            {
                maxSum = W[x][z][val];
                dominantValue = val;
            }
        }
        result[x][z] = val;
        //OR: result[3*x+z] = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for quick answer! Your  algorithm works well for matrix 3x3x3 as you've written . But I used matrix 3x3x3 only as an example. In real case array dimension is about 1000x1000x100.

Comment: The above algorithm has the optimum complexity for this problem. So you can use it by scaling the for loops for different matrix dimensions.

Comment: @vitmol did you reimplement this in python? Because if thats the goal you need to (maybe nontrivially) vectorize it, as this kind of things would be something like 100 times slower otherwise.